# DBT database error, Invalid NUMERIC value: nan

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, dbt

Hi I tried to merge two table in Bigquery but have an error.

```
Database Error in model fact_trips (models/core/fact_trips.sql)
    Invalid NUMERIC value: nan
    compiled Code at target/run/taxi_rides_ny/models/core/fact_trips.sql
```

I have used `dbt_expectations.expect_column_values_to_be_of_type` to check every numeric column and they are passed.

I have null in these columns but I think null is different from nan  right?

Do anyone know how to check which column has invalid value? The error message only show there is an error but no clue on which column and how to fix it?

Here is my repo if you want more details.
https://github.com/ulanliu/DE_zoomcamp/blob/main/w4_analytics_engineering/taxi_rides_ny/models/core/fact_trips.sql

Comment: It is probably a data quality issue. One or more records may have invalid data on that column.

The best thing to do is to run some ad-hoc queries to check that assertion (a CAST to number, for example). Then find and fix those records.

Comment: I have used CAST to make sure pre-merge table data type correct, but the error still happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no explicit casts to `numeric` in this model, so the error is either in an upstream model or caused by the union of `green` and `yellow`.

`stg_green_tripdata` and `stg_yellow_tripdata` are both materialized as views, so it's possible that either (or both) of those models is throwing this error. dbt doesn't `select` from a view after it creates it, so data errors in views are suppressed until the view is queried, which in your case is during the construction of your `fact_trips` model.

I'd start debugging this by doing a simple `select count(*) from stg_green_tripdata` and `select count(*) from stg_yellow_tripdata`. If either (or both) of those error, then you can start to dig deeper. If both of those queries succeed, I would change the materialization on those models to tables and `dbt run` them again, to ensure the simpler queries didn't skip over the problematic cells with indexes.

If you can materialize both upstream models as tables without errors, then I'd examine the `union` more closely. When you `select * from a union select * from b`, you rely on `a` and `b` having the same number of columns with the same types in the same natural order. I'd take about half of the columns and enumerate them in a query `select c, d, e, f from a union select c, d, e, f from b` and see if that succeeds or fails. Keep adding or removing columns until you can isolate the column with a type mismatch.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. I changed the materialization to table and the error comes out. I fixed the data quality now. By the way, `select count(*) from stg_yellow_tripdata` still succeed when the materialized as view. It seems like `view` will skip the error. Anyway, thanks again!